# Exiting EditMode When View Disappears

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I enter the `EditMode` with `EditButton` and I want to leave it when my `view` disappear so the `EditMode` will not continue to the next `view`, here is my code :

```
@State var array = [1,2,3,4]

var body : some View {
  VStack{
    HStack{
      Spacer()
      EditButton()
    }
    List{
       ForEach(self.array){ int in
            Text(int)
       }
    }
  }
}
```

When the user moves to a different view with a different list, without pressing Done on the `EditButton` before hand, the `EditMode` stays, but I want it to become `.inactive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Environment(\.editMode)` and set it to `.inactive` in `onDisappear`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
        }
        .onDisappear {
            editMode?.wrappedValue = .inactive
        }
    }
}
```